# Grab filename to use on command line

Tags: command-line

I have a long filename which I would like to store somehow and use it like copy/paste on the command line. I need to input an ISO filename into the command line, which will be painstaking without a way to copy it. How would I do this?

Comment: What's wrong with copy/paste? Is this a programming question, if so what language are you using?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.